# stopPropagation does not stop the parent action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm putting a input inside a a-tag, and I want to stop the link when clicking to change the value in the input. Like this:

> html

```
<div id="contain">
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" id="link">
        <input id="clickme" type="text" value="1"></input> 
        Buy
    </a>
</div>
```

> jQuery

```
$('#clickme').focus(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#clickme').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GKvw3/1/
result is that it still goes to stackoverflow.com. Any ideas why this is?

**EDIT**
My real scenario is that I got markup like this below. Now what I do is that when somebody click anywhere inside the TR it take the link href. So the problem becomes that submitting the form (not in markup) will cause the link.. therefore I want to do what I explained above and that's why I use the input inside a link in the test.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#">headline</a></td>
    ...
    <td><input type="submit" id="submitme" value="buy"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why would you put an input within a link ? Put them side-by-side if you the label to be clickable and keep the input functionnality.

Comment: It's invalid HTML to put an `input` element inside an `a` element.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is set to use MooTools rather than jQuery, and doesn't match the code you posted in the question.

Comment: dont mind why i want to do this.. this is just a mockup test code for another scenario i got

Comment: We can't answer because the scenaio isn't clear enough.

Comment: It's still not clear. Why did you insert the textbox to the `<a>` link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `preventDefault()`:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Doing it in the `.focus()` is not relevant, you need to "cancel" only the `.click()`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGfkd/6/).

Comment: I just want to be clear on this. is not stopPropagination supose to do that?

Comment: stopPropagination & preventDefault both are different things. read in details here http://dev-tricks.com/event-preventdefault-and-event-stoppropagation-and-event-stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: @Umesh thanks for the link - from what I personally understand, `.stopPropagation()` is used to stop "custom" code from invoking while `.preventDefault()` will prevent the default action of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return false;`:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(e){
    return false;
});
```

[See fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TgcFJ/)

I generally use this when I need to do what you want.